# where I can find h.264 video samples that encoded into different qualities.

Tags: mpeg-dash

I install Wowza media server and I need to test on-demand MPEG dash. where I can find h.264 video samples that encoded into different qualities.

I try to download one file and encoded using ffmpeg, but it is MPEG dash not working with me, it seem I'm doing the ffmpeg in wrong way. because that I'm searching if there are already encoded videos available to download online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download videos from youtube if you want.

Grab [youtube-dl](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/) (requires python), pick a video, display its formats :

```
$ youtube-dl -F https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0

[youtube] 9bZkp7q19f0: Downloading webpage
[youtube] 9bZkp7q19f0: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] 9bZkp7q19f0: Extracting video information
[youtube] 9bZkp7q19f0: Downloading DASH manifest
[info] Available formats for 9bZkp7q19f0:
format code  extension  resolution note
249          webm       audio only DASH audio , opus @ 50k
250          webm       audio only DASH audio , opus @ 70k
251          webm       audio only DASH audio , opus @160k
140          m4a        audio only DASH audio  127k , m4a_dash container, aac  @128k (44100Hz), 3.82MiB
171          webm       audio only DASH audio  128k , vorbis@128k (44100Hz), 3.49MiB
141          m4a        audio only DASH audio  255k , m4a_dash container, aac  @256k (44100Hz), 7.67MiB
278          webm       256x144    DASH video  100k , webm container, vp9, 1fps, video only, 2.57MiB
160          mp4        256x144    DASH video  111k , avc1.4d400c, 12fps, video only, 3.28MiB
242          webm       426x240    DASH video  217k , vp9, 1fps, video only, 5.53MiB
133          mp4        426x240    DASH video  248k , avc1.4d4015, 24fps, video only, 7.37MiB
243          webm       640x360    DASH video  396k , vp9, 1fps, video only, 10.37MiB
134          mp4        640x360    DASH video  622k , avc1.4d401e, 24fps, video only, 15.96MiB
244          webm       854x480    DASH video  872k , vp9, 1fps, video only, 21.15MiB
135          mp4        854x480    DASH video 1141k , avc1.4d401e, 24fps, video only, 29.63MiB
247          webm       1280x720   DASH video 1791k , vp9, 1fps, video only, 40.43MiB
136          mp4        1280x720   DASH video 2265k , avc1.4d401f, 24fps, video only, 56.86MiB
248          webm       1920x1080  DASH video 3295k , vp9, 1fps, video only, 69.28MiB
137          mp4        1920x1080  DASH video 4229k , avc1.640028, 24fps, video only, 113.12MiB
17           3gp        176x144
36           3gp        320x240
5            flv        400x240
43           webm       640x360
18           mp4        640x360
22           mp4        1280x720   (best)
```

Then, if you want to grab the 1080p and 720p H.264 files :

```
youtube-dl -f 136 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0 -o 720p.mp4
youtube-dl -f 137 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0 -o 1080p.mp4
```

You can also grab the separate audio tracks with the corresponding IDs (140, 141..)